# IValueConverter problem

Tags: silverlight

Can i pass complex type to converter as parameter? I have created one converter which basically converts byte array to BitmapImage. However when i pass the byte array as parameter in my binding expression, the parameter is passed as string i.e say my parameter name is PhotosByteArr and when i pass it as parameter to converter, i get the parameter name PhotosByteArr and not the byte array.

This is my binding expression :-

```
 <Image Source="{Binding ConverterParameter=PhotosByteArr, Converter={StaticResource byteArrToBitmap}}" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

PhotosByteArr is instance of byte[].

Any idea what can be wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be

```
{Binding ConverterParameter={Binding PhotosByteArr} ...
```

But I have the question to you. Why are you not writing

```
{Binding Path=PhotosByteArr ...
```

or just

```
{Binding PhotosByteArr ...
```

and then using `value` argument of the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx) method?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var array = (byte[])value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You cannot use bindings for the ConverterParameter as far as i know (i remember to have run into quite some trouble with it in the past at least)

Comment: - I cannot use Binding expression in converterparameter and also if i directly pass it in Path, even the breakpoint in my converter doesn't get hit and i get nothing in image.

Answer (score 2):

To make alpha-mouse's suggestion more explicit, your code should look like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding PhotosByteArr, Converter={StaticResource byteArrToBitmap}}" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

(This is assuming that the byte array will be found from a path alone (i.e the DataContext should contain it))

The binding source will be passed to the converter in the `value` object, the converter parameter offers another input channel if you need additional information. In this case that is not necessary.